# Failed to load module: Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

**Failed to load module: deployment.pms-1.0.0.war Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported"**

[image]

```
wildfly version: 7.1.0.GA

Spring Boot Version: 2.4.2

Java version: 1.8
```

[image]
[image]

**But i can able to deploy on wildfly version 20.0.1.Final**

[image]

Comment: I think jdk.unsupported is since Java 9 and you seem to be running on Java 8

Comment: you are right. i am using java version 15 in my local pc